# How to occasionally provide feedback for a long running Python list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

If you have a long running list comprehension in Python, say:

```
from itertools import combinations

print [w for w in (''.join(c) for c in combinations(words, 2)) if sorted(w) == letters]
```

where words is a list of 200000 words and letters is a list of letters; is there any way to occasionally print out how many words has been processed so far or some other form of progress report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to convert it to a normal loop; don't try to mix in a side-effect function:

```
from itertools import combinations

result = []
count = 0
for w in (''.join(c) for c in combinations(words, 2)):
    if sorted(w) == letters:
        result.append(w)
        count += 1
        if count % 2000 == 0:
            print 'Progress: {0} matching combinations found'.format(count)

print result
```

or, if you want to track combinations tested, move the count before the `if`:

```
from itertools import combinations

result = []
count = 0
for w in (''.join(c) for c in combinations(words, 2)):
    count += 1
    if count % 2000 == 0:
        print 'Progress: {0} combinations scanned'.format(count)

    if sorted(w) == letters:
        result.append(w)

print result
```

Comment: `count += 0`? `;)` Also you don't need `if count` because `count` is incremented before the check and will be at least `1` (at least it's meant to be).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a generator, that can report progress to a log.

```
def log_every(seq, every):
    for i, x in enumerate(seq):
        if (i + 1) % every == 0:
            logging.info('Generated %d', i)
        yield x
```

Use it like this:

```
for c in log_every(combinations(words, 2), 2000):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, there is a *trick* that you can utilize to periodically print out the status of your list comprehension - for example, to print a message on every 10,000th processing while generating a list of only odd numbers you could use:

```
test = [x for x in range(100000)
        if x % 2 or (x % 10000 == 0 and print("Processed: " + str(x)) is None and x % 2)]
```

That being said, this is more of a hack (and it probably doesn't improve the performance given the additional conditionals) so if you need periodic printouts I'd definitely suggest unraveling your loop and dealing with the *reporting* logic in a bit more sane way.